# 'Refresh-save' a file, dock problem?

Tags: linux, terminal, desktop, elementary-os, intellij

A bit of context: I followed the bug reports on Docky ([link1](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/1012912-duplicate-icons-in-plank), [link2](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/1012912-duplicate-icons-in-plank), and all the other links in these links...) and managed to make Plank recognize IntelliJ IDEA using the right StartupWMClass on the .desktop file, it even works in the terminal; typing idea, launches IDEA, with the right icon in the dock, but after I reboot, it doesn't work anymore. What's weirder, if I open idea.desktop with any text editor, and save it, it starts working again until the next reboot, what could be happening?

This is my bash for IDEA, located at /usr/bin/idea:

```
#!/bin/sh
export IDEA_HOME="/opt/idea-IU-135.909/bin"

$IDEA_HOME/idea.sh $*
```

My idea.desktop file at `/usr/share/applications/idea.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=IntellJ IDEA
Comment=The Best Java and Polyglot IDE
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
Exec=idea
Icon=intellij-idea-ultimate-edition
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;Application;Development;
StartupNotify=true
```

At the moment I've solved this issue by forcing an open & save on my `/etc/rc.local` like this:

```
sudo vim /usr/share/applications/idea.desktop
:wq
exit 0
```

What other options do I have? what could be happening here? is there -at least- a better way to open and save a file in the terminal? mine is imho, horrifying.

Comment: Create a copy of the non-working version before you open it w/ a text editor, then open & save it and run `diff` to see if this is something like the addition of a newline at the end of the file.

Comment: Before opening or copying `stat` the file for all possible permissions related properties, then ^do^, then do the permissions checks again and compare.

Comment: What do you mean by ^do^?